# mongoosastic passing payload in suggesters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, mongoosastic

How to pass a payload while indexing documents in completion suggester(elasticsearch) via mongoosastic if it's possible? I couldn't find any documentation in mongoosastic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enabled payloads in the suggester field with `payloads: true`, you can pass payloads for your suggester field as part of the document you will save/index, just like in Elasticsearch.

For example:

```
{
    name: req.params.name,
    lastName: req.params.lastName,
    suggesterField: {
        payload: {
            field: req.params.payload
        }
    }
}
```